# Ubuntu Server unable to create directory in PHP

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I have setup a little Ubuntu Server for developing some web apps.

I have a little script that uses mkdir() to create a directory, but i am getting a permission denied, its a simple command

```
mkdir($directory);
```

The error that im getting is

```
[Tue Jun 21 22:27:25.079075 2016] [:error] [pid 21150] [client 192.168.0.8:55413] PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in .........
```

Im also getting permission denied for a few other commands like ftp_get()

When i check the phpinfo() the upload_tmp_dir is set to no value.

I am not very good at server admin so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I setup the server from a tutorial, then setup my virtual host from another tutorial.

Thanks Guys :)

Comment: This is not a PHP problem. The process that runs PHP does not have the permissions required to execute your requests. You need to configure your server correctly. Find out which user is running PHP for you (if this is apache it may be www-data), when add this user to the correct group so it can do what you want in the directories. You may also want to include more information about user(s), groups and their permissions and ask at the ubuntu SO site.

Comment: @OptimusCrime .. sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www ... would that be a permanent solution to my problem?

Comment: a better approach would be to add the user to the correct group

Comment: @OptimusCrime .. Sorry about the daft questions, but is there any chance you could hook me up an answer letting me know how i do that ... im not having any luck with my searches. thank you

Comment: That would be something like `useradd -G www-data www-data`. This adds the user `www-data` to the group `www-data`. Check which group owns the directory `/var/www/`, and also check which user runs apache.

Answer (score 0):

you need to confirm that the user starting the PHP service has permission to write to the directory,if not. you can try command `sudo chown -R php_user /which_directory_you_want_to_mkdir`, than inout root password and run program again. Good luck.

My English is not very good, sorry

Comment: Hey, this is only a temp solution though isnt it? ... If the app is creating the directories, the permissions need to be set all the time

Comment: i do not really know what do you want to do,but according to you code and error message , maybe you can check path '$directory' that be sure you have permission with it.